# Get a JSON value returning undefined

Tags: json, undefined

I have extracted JSON content from [this web site](http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=AAPL:NASDAQ)

Have created some code in Google Script Editor...

```
var urlresponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText().substring(3);
var jsondata = JSON.stringify(urlresponse);
var jsonparseddata = JSON.parse(jsondata);
```

I can print the `jsonparseddata` to the logs as below.
But cannot seem to get a value or even attempt to iterate.
Have spent hours trying various online examples, need help. Thanks

When using jsonparseddata[0].id the logs return 'undefined'

```
[{
    "id": "22144",
    "t": "AAPL",
    "e": "NASDAQ",
    "l": "90.52",
    "l_fix": "90.52",
    "l_cur": "90.52",
    "s": "0",
    "ltt": "4:00PM EDT",
    "lt": "May 13, 4:00PM EDT",
    "lt_dts": "2016-05-13T16:00:02Z",
    "c": "+0.18",
    "c_fix": "0.18",
    "cp": "0.20",
    "cp_fix": "0.20",
    "ccol": "chg",
    "pcls_fix": "90.34"
}]
```

Comment: Take a look at [Parse JSON in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: You have a JSON array. Do `jsonparseddata[0].id` to read the id, `jsonparseddata[0].e` to see "NASDAQ" etc

Comment: I've 'parsed' the JSON.  But I need to extract values

Comment: jsonparseddata[0].id returns 'undefined' in the log.

Comment: Try `jsonparseddata[0]['id']` instead

Comment: OK - think I'm getting somewhere. jsonparseddata is a string not an object.   The problem right at the start is the JSON web site content begins with // so I have used substring to get rid of this.  But now probably need to get back into a JSON Object which I thought Parse would do

Comment: Cracked it -   var jsondata = JSON.stringify(eval(urlresponse)); now jsonparseddata returns as an object. The rest of the code now responds correctly to jsonparseddata[0].id.   Will leave iteration for tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Added logging to show the type of each variable.

As I used .getContentText().substring(3); for the urlresponse due to badly formatted JSON on the web site, this made each subsequent variable a string.

Using EVAL - var jsondata = JSON.stringify(eval(urlresponse));
Now the jsonparseddata is an object and jsonparseddata[0].id is returning a value, instead of undefined.